# DotNetNuke Removes Query String Parameters When Opened from the Excel

Tags: c#, dotnetnuke

I have some DNN links in an Excel sheet.  The links contain extra query string variables for a custom module. The initial click of the link from the excel sheet will cause DNN to display the login page, along with the URL redirect and once logged in, will redirect to the appropriate page with the original URL and as expected.

However, any subsequent clicks on any links in the excel sheet, which open a new tab, will have any additional query string variables stripped from the URL.  The original user is still logged in because the tab recognizes the earlier session and login, but the URL is no longer as expected.

So the problem is to view the expected results user has to log out from the portal and log in again every time. Why the Query string gets stripped off from the URL automatically even when there is no custom logic written in the modules for URL rewriting.

Comment: Additionally this problem only occurs when limited number of users are given permissions on that page.